# Safari 6 Total page size (kb)

Tags: safari, console, size, page-size

Since the new version of Safari 6 there is a new developer console.
In the developer console, you can view the timeline, network requests and such. 
The only thing I am missing is "total page size."

Is there a way to see the whole page size in kb again, or did Apple remove that?
Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Why don't you just use Firefox?
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087991/safari-6-total-page-size-kb

Comment: now you have page size in Safari 7 :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, just use Safari 7. It has the feature you are asking.